# Is it possible to load the progressive web app manifest file from authenticated site?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, basic-authentication

I'm having the progressive web app index.html page and assets in a SharePoint document library. I need to authenticate when accessing the index.html page. But the manifest.json file as linked as `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json.txt">` does not have the required authentication cookie when requested from the index.html page. Note that SharePoint does not serve .jon files, that is why it ends with .txt. Is there a way to retrieve the manifest from an authenticated site?

It works when I have the manifest on an anonymously accessible location, i.e. outside of SharePoint (I now use my dropbox). In that case I need to specify a full path for the start_url. But this is not a really nice deployment model because I need to deploy files to two different locations...

Comment: Asked question also at https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/535

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is possible to use a manifest link on an authenticated site, but to make sure the that credentials are passed along on the request for the manifest use:

`<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json.txt" crossorigin="use-credentials">`

Answer given at https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/535 by https://github.com/dominickng.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. I have currently hosted my manifest file on s3 buckets of amazon.  Simply add link to manifest. You might need to enable cross origin sharing if domains are different.